# change main product image by select a image from image swatch

Tags: magento-1.7, image, custom-options, switcher

i want to change the main image and more views images on product view page by select a image from image swatch or any name from drop-down please suggest me any extension which achieve this function thanks

Answer (score 1):

I hope you need to change the products image based on the selected option for the configurable products.

This website has step by step instruction to do it and tested in magento 1.7 and 1.8.
http://magehelper.blogspot.in/2014/02/magento-change-product-image-on-view.html

If you need an extension, this one is good http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/image-based-dynamic-configurable-products-by-amasty.html  [commercial]

Comment: thanks Franc u make it easy for me i also found some paid extension which exactly solve my problem